# Reproducibility in TensorFlow Bayesian Neural Network (DenseVariational layers)

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, tensorflow-probability

I am training the following BNN with TensorFlow `DenseVariational` layers and every training that I do I obtain significantly different predictions for mean and confidence intervals. I expect that running again the same training would lead to similar performance.

Here they are the resulting plots of the predictions of 3 different training sessions, I don't think the problem is the number of epochs since 100K is a huge number for this simple problem:

[image: Prediction of 1° training]

[image: Prediction of 2° training]

[image: Prediction of 3° training]

Here's the code:

Imports

```
import tensorflow as tf
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
from tqdm import tqdm_notebook as tqdm
import tensorflow_probability as tfp

from tensorflow.keras.layers import Input, Dense, Concatenate
from tensorflow.keras.models import Model
from tensorflow.keras.optimizers import Adam
from tensorflow.keras import layers, callbacks

tfd = tfp.distributions
tfb = tfp.bijectors
```

Create fake data

```
def create_sine_data(n = 2048):
    np.random.seed(32)
    x = np.linspace(0,1*2*np.pi,n)
    y1 = 3*np.sin(x)
    y1 = np.concatenate((np.zeros(60), y1+np.random.normal(0,0.15*np.abs(y1),n),np.zeros(60)))
    x=np.concatenate((np.linspace(-3,0,60),np.linspace(0,3*2*np.pi,n),np.linspace(3*2*np.pi,3*2*np.pi+3,60)))
    y2 = 0.1*x+1
    y=y1+y2
    return x,y

## use custom function to simulate some data 
x,y = create_sine_data(2048) # Note that the model has been trained with 2048 data points
plt.scatter(x=x,y=y,marker='.', alpha=0.5, s=30)
plt.title("simulated data")
plt.xlabel("x")
plt.ylabel("y")
```

Create BNN with TFP DenseVariational layers

```
def NLL(y, distr): 
    return -distr.log_prob(y) 
def normal_sp(params):
    return tfd.Normal(loc=params[:,:1],\
                      scale=1e-5 + 0.00001*tf.keras.backend.exp(params[:,1:]))# both parameters are learnable

def random_gaussian_initializer(shape, dtype):
    n = int(shape / 2)
    loc_norm = tf.random_normal_initializer(mean=0., stddev=0.1)
    loc = tf.Variable(
        initial_value=loc_norm(shape=(n,), dtype=dtype)
    )
    scale_norm = tf.random_normal_initializer(mean=-3., stddev=0.1)
    scale = tf.Variable(
        initial_value=scale_norm(shape=(n,), dtype=dtype)
    )
    return tf.concat([loc, scale], 0)


# Define the prior weight distribution as Normal of mean=0 and stddev=1.
def prior_trainable(kernel_size, bias_size=0, dtype=None):
    n = kernel_size + bias_size
    return tf.keras.Sequential([
      tfp.layers.VariableLayer(n, dtype=dtype),
      tfp.layers.DistributionLambda(lambda t: tfd.Independent(
          tfd.Normal(loc=t, scale=1),
          reinterpreted_batch_ndims=1)),
    ])

# The posterior is modeled as n_weights independent Normal distribution with learnable parameters
def posterior_mean_field(kernel_size, bias_size=0, dtype=None):
    n = kernel_size + bias_size
    return tf.keras.Sequential([
      tfp.layers.VariableLayer(2 * n, dtype=dtype,\
                               initializer=lambda shape, dtype: random_gaussian_initializer(shape, dtype), trainable=True),
      tfp.layers.DistributionLambda(lambda t: tfd.Independent(
          tfd.Normal(loc=t[..., :n],
                     scale=1e-5 + 0.001*tf.nn.softplus(0.54 + t[..., n:])),
          reinterpreted_batch_ndims=1)),
    ])

def create_probabilistic_bnn_model(train_size):

    model = tf.keras.Sequential([
        tf.keras.Input(shape=(1,)),
        tfp.layers.DenseVariational(128, posterior_mean_field, prior_trainable, kl_weight=1/train_size, activation='relu', kl_use_exact=True),
        tfp.layers.DenseVariational(64, posterior_mean_field, prior_trainable, kl_weight=1/train_size, activation='relu', kl_use_exact=True),
        tfp.layers.DenseVariational(32, posterior_mean_field, prior_trainable, kl_weight=1/train_size, activation='relu', kl_use_exact=True),
        tfp.layers.DenseVariational(2, posterior_mean_field, prior_trainable, kl_weight=1/train_size, kl_use_exact=True),
        tfp.layers.DistributionLambda(normal_sp),
    ])
    return model
```

Instantiate and fit the BNN

```
train_size = x.shape[0]
batch_size = 512

optimizer = tf.optimizers.Adam(learning_rate=0.0002)

keras_BNN = create_probabilistic_bnn_model(train_size=train_size)
keras_BNN.compile(optimizer=optimizer,
                  loss=NLL,
                  metrics=[tf.keras.metrics.MeanAbsoluteError()]
                 ) 
keras_BNN.build((None,1))
keras_BNN.summary()

history_keras_BNN = keras_BNN.fit(x, y, epochs=100000, verbose=1, batch_size=batch_size)

plt.plot(history_keras_BNN.history['loss'], label='loss', linewidth=3)
plt.legend()
plt.ylabel('Variational Free Energy')
plt.xlabel('Epochs')
plt.ylim(top=100, bottom=0)
plt.show()
```

Monte Carlo experiment (predictions)

```
x_pred = np.arange(-10,30,0.3) 
# MC experiment
runs = 200
preds = np.zeros((runs, len(x_pred)))
for i in tqdm(range(0, runs)):
    preds[i,:]=np.reshape(keras_BNN.predict(x_pred), len(x_pred))
preds_std = np.std(preds, axis=0)
preds_mean = np.mean(preds, axis=0)

plt.title("Predictions")
plt.plot(x_pred, preds_mean, c='r', linestyle='--', label='mean')
plt.plot(x_pred, np.quantile(preds, 0.025, axis=0), c='k', linestyle='--', label='CI 99%')
plt.plot(x_pred, np.quantile(preds, 0.975, axis=0), c='k', linestyle='--')
plt.scatter(x, y, s=5)
plt.legend()
plt.ylim(-10,10)
plt.show()
```

Comment: I think you assumption is wrong, Variational Inference methods have much more variability than standard neural networks.

Comment: In this case, in order to reproduce, you need to draw exactly same values from your variational posterior in every epoch.

Comment: @Frightera Thanks for your comment. Do you know how to draw exactly same values from variational posterior in TensorFlow Probability with DenseVariational layers?

Comment: I don't think it would be possible without editing the source code, DenseVariational uses `tf.convert_to_tensor()` internally to get samples. Relevant method is here: https://github.com/tensorflow/probability/blob/f5541be80d2e118a3875ec795285927f5580465a/tensorflow_probability/python/layers/internal/distribution_tensor_coercible.py#L165-L224

Comment: Setting a random seed in tensorflow would work, it is not just the variational posterior but also the samples used during training.

Comment: @Dr.Snoopy thank you. I tried to set the seed, but still I obtained slightly different training. I also removed the final DistributionLambda layer for reproducibility

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean the accuracy, you are trying to fits those random scatters escape sine values with a two-line that is quantiles. Start every time they will try to match of close matching each time and it is quantiles.

It is consider of the value in ranges.

**[ Sample ]:**

```
import tensorflow as tf
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from tqdm import tqdm_notebook as tqdm
import tensorflow_probability as tfp

from tensorflow.keras.layers import Input, Dense, Concatenate
from tensorflow.keras.models import Model
from tensorflow.keras.optimizers import Adam
from tensorflow.keras import layers, callbacks

import os
from os.path import exists

tfd = tfp.distributions     
tfb = tfp.bijectors         

"""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""
[PhysicalDevice(name='/physical_device:GPU:0', device_type='GPU')]
None
"""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""
physical_devices = tf.config.experimental.list_physical_devices('GPU')
assert len(physical_devices) > 0, "Not enough GPU hardware devices available"
config = tf.config.experimental.set_memory_growth(physical_devices[0], True)
print(physical_devices)
print(config)

"""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""
: Variables
"""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""   
learning_rate = 0.0002
batch_size = 512
epochs = 100000

checkpoint_path = "F:\\models\\checkpoint\\" + os.path.basename(__file__).split('.')[0] + "\\TF_DataSets_01.h5"
checkpoint_dir = os.path.dirname(checkpoint_path)

if not exists(checkpoint_dir) : 
    os.mkdir(checkpoint_dir)
    print("Create directory: " + checkpoint_dir)

"""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""
: Definition / Class
"""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""
def create_sine_data(n = 2048):

    # pi = np.linspace(0, 180, n)
    pi = 3.141592653589793
    start = 0.0
    stop = 1.0 * 2.0 * pi
    num = n
    
    x = tf.linspace( start, stop, num, name='linspace', axis=0 )
    y1 = 3 * tf.math.sin( x )
    
    escape_sine = tf.random.normal(
        shape=( n, ),
        mean=0.0,
        stddev=0.15 * tf.math.abs( y1, name='abs' ),
        dtype=tf.dtypes.float32,
        seed=32,
        name=None
    )
    
    
    
    y1 = tf.concat( (tf.zeros(60), y1 + escape_sine, tf.zeros(60)), axis=0, name='concat' )
    initial_degree = tf.experimental.numpy.arange( -3, 0, 3 / 60, dtype=tf.float32 )
    midring_degree = tf.experimental.numpy.arange( 0, 3 * 2 * pi, ( 3 * 2 * pi) / n, dtype=tf.float32 )
    skipped_degree = tf.experimental.numpy.arange( 3 * 2 * pi, 3 * 2 * pi + 3, ( 3 * 2 * pi - 3 * 2 * pi + 3 ) / 60, dtype=tf.float32 )
    
    x = tf.concat(( initial_degree.numpy(), midring_degree.numpy(), skipped_degree.numpy()), axis=0, name='concat')
    y2 = 0.1 * x + 1
    y = y1 + y2

    return x, y

def NLL(y, distr): 
    return -distr.log_prob(y) 
def normal_sp(params):
    return tfd.Normal(loc=params[:,:1],\
                      scale=1e-5 + 0.00001*tf.keras.backend.exp(params[:,1:]))# both parameters are learnable

def random_gaussian_initializer(shape, dtype):
    n = int(shape / 2)
    loc_norm = tf.random_normal_initializer(mean=0., stddev=0.1)
    loc = tf.Variable(
        initial_value=loc_norm(shape=(n,), dtype=dtype)
    )
    scale_norm = tf.random_normal_initializer(mean=-3., stddev=0.1)
    scale = tf.Variable(
        initial_value=scale_norm(shape=(n,), dtype=dtype)
    )
    return tf.concat([loc, scale], 0)


# Define the prior weight distribution as Normal of mean=0 and stddev=1.
def prior_trainable(kernel_size, bias_size=0, dtype=None):
    n = kernel_size + bias_size
    return tf.keras.Sequential([
      tfp.layers.VariableLayer(n, dtype=dtype),
      tfp.layers.DistributionLambda(lambda t: tfd.Independent(
          tfd.Normal(loc=t, scale=1),
          reinterpreted_batch_ndims=1)),
    ])

# The posterior is modeled as n_weights independent Normal distribution with learnable parameters
def posterior_mean_field(kernel_size, bias_size=0, dtype=None):
    n = kernel_size + bias_size
    return tf.keras.Sequential([
      tfp.layers.VariableLayer(2 * n, dtype=dtype,\
                               initializer=lambda shape, dtype: random_gaussian_initializer(shape, dtype), trainable=True),
      tfp.layers.DistributionLambda(lambda t: tfd.Independent(
          tfd.Normal(loc=t[..., :n],
                     scale=1e-5 + 0.001*tf.nn.softplus(0.54 + t[..., n:])),
          reinterpreted_batch_ndims=1)),
    ])

def create_probabilistic_bnn_model(train_size):

    model = tf.keras.Sequential([
        tf.keras.Input(shape=(1,)),
        tfp.layers.DenseVariational(128, posterior_mean_field, prior_trainable, kl_weight=1/train_size, activation='relu', kl_use_exact=True),
        tfp.layers.DenseVariational(64, posterior_mean_field, prior_trainable, kl_weight=1/train_size, activation='relu', kl_use_exact=True),
        tfp.layers.DenseVariational(32, posterior_mean_field, prior_trainable, kl_weight=1/train_size, activation='relu', kl_use_exact=True),
        tfp.layers.DenseVariational(2, posterior_mean_field, prior_trainable, kl_weight=1/train_size, kl_use_exact=True),
        tfp.layers.DistributionLambda(normal_sp),
    ])
    return model

"""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""
: Callback
"""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""
class custom_callback(tf.keras.callbacks.Callback):
    def on_epoch_end(self, epoch, logs={}):
        if( logs['loss'] <= 0.2 ):
            self.model.stop_training = True
    
custom_callback = custom_callback()

"""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""
: Tasks
"""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""   
x, y = create_sine_data( )
plt.plot( x, y )
plt.xlabel("Sample Sine")
plt.show( )
plt.close( )

train_size = x.shape[0]
# batch_size = 512

optimizer = tf.optimizers.Adam( learning_rate=learning_rate )

keras_BNN = create_probabilistic_bnn_model(train_size=train_size)
keras_BNN.compile(optimizer=optimizer,
                  loss=NLL,
                  metrics=[tf.keras.metrics.MeanAbsoluteError()]
                 ) 
keras_BNN.build((None,1))
keras_BNN.summary()

"""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""
: FileWriter
"""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""
if exists(checkpoint_path) :
    model.load_weights(checkpoint_path)
    print("model load: " + checkpoint_path)
    input("Press Any Key!")

history_keras_BNN = keras_BNN.fit( x, y, epochs=epochs, verbose=1, batch_size=batch_size, callbacks=[custom_callback] )
model.save_weights(checkpoint_path)

plt.plot(history_keras_BNN.history['loss'], label='loss', linewidth=3)
plt.legend()
plt.ylabel('Variational Free Energy')
plt.xlabel('Epochs')
plt.ylim(top=100, bottom=0)
plt.show()


x_pred = tf.experimental.numpy.arange( -10, 30, 0.3, dtype=tf.float32 )

# MC experiment
runs = 200
preds = tf.zeros([runs, len(x_pred)]).numpy()
for i in tqdm(range(0, runs)):
    preds[i,:] = tf.reshape( keras_BNN.predict(x_pred), len(x_pred), name='reshape' ).numpy()
    
preds_std = tf.experimental.numpy.std( preds, axis=0, keepdims=None ).numpy()
preds_mean = tf.experimental.numpy.mean( preds, axis=0, dtype=None, out=None, keepdims=None ).numpy()

plt.title("Predictions")
plt.plot(x_pred, preds_mean, c='r', linestyle='--', label='mean')

lower_Q = tfp.stats.quantiles(
    preds,
    134 - 1,
    axis=None,
    interpolation=None,
    keepdims=None,
    validate_args=False,
    name=None
).numpy()

upper_Q = tfp.stats.quantiles(
    preds,
    134 - 1,
    axis=None,
    interpolation=None,
    keepdims=None,
    validate_args=False,
    name=None
).numpy()

plt.plot(x_pred, lower_Q, c='k', linestyle='--', label='CI 99%')
plt.plot(x_pred, upper_Q, c='k', linestyle='--')
plt.scatter(x, y, s=5)
plt.legend()
plt.ylim(-10,10)
plt.show()
```

Comment: Thank you, but I don't get your point. I also tried to run your code.